# Kdenlive Render Effects

Tags: video, video-editor, effects, linux, playback

I'm using Kdenlive on Linux Mint 16, and I was finding that my keyframed "Box Blur" effect was significantly slowing down playback, and so I thought there might be a way to render the effects on a clip, essentially making them "non-editable", to speed up playback.
Is there such a function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can preview effects using **timeline preview rendering** since version 16.08 ([video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwC-ZPnxsVs)):

1. Set in and out points using I and O keys for the area in which your effect is active.
2. In the main menu in **Timeline/Timeline Preview** press **Add preview zone**.
3. In the same menu, press **Start Preview Render** and wait until the red bar turns green at the top of the timeline.

Any change to the area - including moving clips or adding effects to clips in it - will result in requiring to re-render to regain the playback speed enhancement.

In case 16.08 or later is not available on Linux Mint yet, you might be able to install it manually ([video guide](http://youtu.be/fTqegNq4Y6c)):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kdenlive/kdenlive-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kdenlive
```